# Why am I getting this error "__str__ returned non-string" Django

Tags: django, django-models

I get this error in the admin page only when referencing the object (as foreign key when adding entries in another model) but when I create an entrie of that model it works well.

I have this tuple of choices for a django field

```
    INSCRIPTION = 'INS'
    CROSSFIT = 'CRF'
    FUNCTIONAL = 'FUN'
    KICKBOXING = 'KBX'
    ALL_ACCESS = 'ALL'
    UNSPECIFIED = 'UNS'

    PAYMENT_CHOICES = (
        (INSCRIPTION, 'Inscription'),
        (CROSSFIT, 'Crossfit'),
        (FUNCTIONAL, 'Functional'),
        (KICKBOXING, 'Kickboxing'),
        (ALL_ACCESS, 'All access'),
        (UNSPECIFIED, 'Unspecified')
    )


    payment_code = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default=UNSPECIFIED)    
    amount = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        choice_index = 0
        if self.payment_code == self.CROSSFIT:
            choice_index = 1
        elif self.payment_code == self.FUNCTIONAL:
            choice_index = 2    
        elif self.payment_code == self.KICKBOXING:
            choice_index = 3    
        elif self.payment_code == self.ALL_ACCESS:
            choice_index = 4

        payment_name = str(self.PAYMENT_CHOICES[choice_index][1])
        return payment_name
```

I get the error when I try to add an entry to this model

```
class Payment(models.Model):

    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, on_delete=models.SET("UNS"))
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payment_type
```

Comment: please post the detail in error page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Payment(models.Model):

    payment_type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, on_delete=models.SET("UNS"))
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    reference = models.IntegerField()
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payment_type
```

change `__str__` to

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.payment_type.__str__()
```

`__str__` method only accept string as return value,not FK instance.

By the way, the `__str__` method in another model :

```
def __str__(self):
    choice_index = 0
    if self.payment_code == self.CROSSFIT:
        choice_index = 1
    elif self.payment_code == self.FUNCTIONAL:
        choice_index = 2    
    elif self.payment_code == self.KICKBOXING:
        choice_index = 3    
    elif self.payment_code == self.ALL_ACCESS:
        choice_index = 4

    payment_name = str(self.PAYMENT_CHOICES[choice_index][1])
    return payment_name
```

can simplify to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_payment_code_display()
```

see [get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Comment: I have add some code to  simplify `__str__` method in another model, have a look.

Comment: I knew there should be a simpler way to do it! Haha thank you that was very useful.